# Is it possible to remove the frame of an Android custom dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-gui

Any ideas if there's a way to remove the frame of a custom made dialog?

If no, what would be the best way to show a content of an XML over the current activity?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your dialog, enter a second parameter which is the theme for the dialog:
http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/09/theme-android-dialog/